# Text suggestions and autocomplete windows/chrome equivalent to MAC

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I'm trying to find any software,extension or built-in functionality on a windows/chrome that can replicate the functionality of a mac using the keyboard text autocomplete. [here](http://www.imore.com/how-create-text-shortcuts-os-x-yosemite)

For example. If I type "Bacon" it prints out "I love Bacon" any help would be appreciated.